# problem installing application on android

Tags: android, installation

I have developed an application for android in android sdk 2.2 But when i tried to install an application on mobile with version 2.1, it throws an error "There is problem parsing the package". How do i solve this error? thanks in advance

Comment: Check your package name in AndroidManifest.xml, might be any other app with same package name exists.

Comment: There are plenty of topics about this, please look around on google before asking a question.

Answer (score 0):

Your application works only on sdk version 2.2 and above,if you need to support on sdk version 2.1,choose sdk version below 2.1 sdk version.

Answer (score 0):

Check following parameters on your manifest file

android:minSdkVersion

```
This is an integer that indicates the minimum API Level required to properly run your application.
```

android:targetSdkVersion

```
An integer designating the API Level that the application is targetting.
```

More details on

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-sdk-element.html

Answer (score 0):

you have developped your application on version 2.2, which means that your app will work only on sdk 2.2 or higher , because possibly you have used some packages and classes which arent exist on sdk2.1 ,

to make your app work on sdk2.1 , change the sdk of your application to 2.1 , and modify ( if necessary ) the code that is not supported on 2.1 .